# Mark Attendance of two to three years in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a program which insert attendance of student, but there is no history record against all student, I have made logic of one month ( through which one student attendance is mark on particular month)

```
         string values = "[RG_No],[Date],[Shift],[IsPresent]";
         string Query ="";
        if(isleave != 2)
            values += ",[IsLeave]";
        Query = "insert into tbl_StudentAttendance ("+values+") values("+txtRegistrationNo.Text+",'" +date+ "',"+txtShift.Text+","+isPresent;

        if(isleave !=2)
        {
            Query += "," +isleave;
        }
        Query += ")" ;
        DAL.Error.errObjects err = c.ExecuteCommand(Query);
```

this Idea is successful on one month, per student. through which I passed RegistrationNo, Shift , Year and Month one time , and CSV data is entered on richTextBox like

first digit is particular day of month and second is for Leave ( if student is on leave it marks on this day as 1, else 0)

> 2,1
>
> 3,1
>
> 4,0

all other day which is not define in richTexbox is mark as present except Sunday..

is there any other way through I can enter per year, instead of month automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for?

Comment: @JacobRaines I have Student Attendance of two years, but students counting is greater than 100, what I want is, any dynamical approach through which I can mark per student attendance of one year. I have made this logic on per month. but I want to make it happen as one year